# Find phonome and duration

Tags: python, phoneme

I was wondering if anyone knows of a python tool that finds phonemes from a text, as well as their duration.

In short, I want a forced alignment tool like aeneas, but I want the phonemes and their duration.

Thank you!

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what kind of data you have, but I assume it's audio files with their corresponding orthographic transcriptions.

In that case, the [Montreal Forced Aligner](https://montrealcorpustools.github.io/Montreal-Forced-Aligner/) might be suitable (there is link to the executable on that page).
It is based on Kaldi, so for more robust and comprehensive solution, the [kaldi-dnn-ali-gop](https://github.com/tbright17/kaldi-dnn-ali-gop) repo provides more powerful options.